# Separar un String los números y las letras

Tags: jquery

Saludos compañeros,

Recurro a su acostumbrada y valiosa colaboración con una situación:

Tengo una dirección que es un String y quiero pasarlo a un array en Jquery de la siguiente manera:

```
    var direccion = $('#address_new').val();
    var direccionArray = numbersString.split(' ');
```

Hasta ahí voy bien, Pero hay una parte de la dirección que tiene un número con letra pegada por ejemplo: 14A. Necesito separar los números de la letra. Alguien sabe como se puede hacer desde Jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En jquery no se, creo que no hay nada, pero en javascript puedes probar esto:

```js
a = "A 14A A texto de prueba 23A AA34 AA45AA"
a = a.match(/[a-z]+|[^a-z]+/gi).join(" ").replace(/\s+/g, " ");
console.log(a)
```

**donde:**

- **match()** es, según su [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> El método match() se usa para obtener todas las ocurrencias de una
> expresión regular dentro de una cadena.

- **[a-z]+|[^a-z]+** es una expresión regular que separa letras `[a-z]+`de *no letras* `[^a-z]`
- **gi** son los parámetros pasados a la búsqueda, donde **g** significa global y es para que no se pare en la primera coincidencia y continue hasta el final, e **i** es para ignorar mayúsculas de minúsculas.

Como eso devuelve un array de coincidencias, tenemos que unirlas de nuevo, y lo hacemos mediante

- **join()**, que, de nuevo, tal como dice su [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

> El método join() une todos los elementos de una matriz (o un objeto
> similar a una matriz) en una cadena y devuelve esta cadena.

Al cual le ponemos como parámetro un separador de espacio `(" ")`, el cual va a generarnos otro problema después, que en determinados casos los espacios son demasiados, asi que aplicamos lo siguiente para reducirlos a uno solo entre los elementos de la cadena con mediante esta instrucción:

- **replace(/\s+/g, " ")**, que de nuevo, su [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) dice:

> El método replace() devuelve una nueva cadena con algunas o todas las
> coincidencias de un patrón, siendo cada una de estas coincidencias
> reemplazadas por remplazo. El patrón puede ser una cadena o una
> RegExp, y el reemplazo puede ser una cadena o una función que será
> llamada para cada coincidencia.

La expresión **RegExp** pasada a `replace` es la siguiente:

- **/\s+/g**, donde `\s` encuentra el espacio en blanco, y el símbolo `+` indica una o más coincidencias. Y la `g` lo mismo de antes, búsqueda global.

Y el reemplazo del `replace` es este:

- **`" "`**, o sea, un solo espacio.

Por lo tanto, le estamos diciendo a `replace` que allí donde encuentre más de un espacio o un espacio solo lo sustituya por solo un espacio.

De este modo conseguimos separar todos los números ("no letras") de las letras esten donde esten en una cadena y lo devolvemos separados por simples espacios.

Comment: masterguru.... muchísimas gracias por tu repuesta y por el paso a paso de la explicación. Me quedó bastante claro y me funcionó perfecto... Saludos